# scheduler method not valid by type system

Tags: code-coverage

this is my scheduler class-

```
global class BatchEndTripRecordsScheduler implements Schedulable {
   global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
      BatchEndTripRecords betr = new BatchEndTripRecords();
       Database.executeBatch(betr); 
   }
}
```

this is my test class-

```
@IsTest
public class TestBatchEndTripRecordsScheduler {
   public static testMethod void EndtripScheduler()
   {
       System.Test.startTest();
       BatchEndTripRecords bet = new BatchEndTripRecords();
       String chron = '0 0 12 15 9 ? 2019';        
       String JobID = system.schedule('job', chron, bet);
       System.test.stopTest();
   }
}
```

m getting this error on saving-
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void schedule(String, String, BatchEndTripRecords) from the type System

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the instance of scheduler class and not the batch class

```
BatchEndTripRecordsScheduler bet = new BatchEndTripRecordsScheduler ();
String chron = '0 0 12 15 9 ? 2019';        
String JobID = system.schedule('job', chron, bet);
```

We use `system.schedule`  to schedule the scheduler class that's why we need to pass the instance of it and not of actual batch class.

Comment: thanks Tushar for the help there are many questions on my side ill be posting pla do help if you can